# Is it possible to simulate a file creation exception in Java on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, file, exception, testing

I had a simple test to make sure that an ant task was behaving properly, and so put in illegal file characters for windows and linux like so:

```
@Test(expected=BuildException.class)
public void destinationDirectoryCreationException() throws Exception {
    backupTask.setSrcDir(testResourceDirectory);
    backupTask.setDestDir(new File("?/"));
    backupTask.execute();
}
```

Unfortunately, the reason that `/` is an illegal file character is that it's the path separator, so this will simply create the directory as normal.

Also char `0` or `nul` is interpreted by various apis (notably the native file apis and eclipse's debug variable explorer) as the end of stream and so just ignores everything afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

No. Linux is far too awesome to fail for your pathetic little test.

*Ok, so osgx actually proposed a solution that will work for my test in particular (if (s)he made an answer, he could get 15 rep ;)); make the directory a sub-directory of one that doesn't exist. e.g. `backupTask.setDestDir(new File("/\\/?/"));`. The only problem is that it's mildly different from the original test, but I'm ok with that.*

*Also note that (I believe) it will still succeed in creating the folder if `.mkdirs()` was called instead of `mkdir()`*

Comment: try to create file in root dir or in non-existend folder.

Comment: I want you to check, will it help or not

Comment: Yes it helped immensely, `backupTask.setDestDir(new File("/\\/?/"));` did the trick

Comment: 1 for not helpful, +2 for awesomeness = +1